# Blender Equivalent to Padding?

Tags: modeling

Does Blender have any function to create a sort of padding/margin in *Edit Mode*? Let's say I have a plane and I'd like to have a smaller plane inside of this first one with even distance towards all the edges.

Please take a look at the image to see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *Inset Faces*. It doesn't do it exactly like in your image. Instead it looks like this.
[image]

Select the faces you want to inset and press <kbd>I</kbd> and drag the mouse. It works with  multiple faces as well.
[image]

And if you do <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> when you have multiple faces selected, it will inset them individually.
[image]

Instead of dragging the mouse, you can type the inset distance immediately after <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

This doesn't pad the plane outwards, increasing its size, but rather insets within the current size. This can, of course, be remedied by scaling it up before insetting. Also, as you can see, the corners are handled differently.

Comment: This answers my question 100%, thank you so much !!!

Comment: @StefanoDeLaBurczymuchito Glad I could help. :)